# Server 2012: System writer is not found in the backup

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2012, vss

I recently installed the `Windows Server Backup` feature on my Windows Server 2012. When I try to create a backup (full) I get the following error: `System writer is not found in the backup.`

I followed this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009272 <sub>*(Microsoft link dead. Archived version [here](https://archive.is/0pHzE). Also [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/622316/application-capi2-event-513-cryptographic-services-failed-while-processing-the) is a detailed walkthrough of the MSKB article.)*</sub> MS KB article by using `takeown` and `icacls`, restarted `cryptsvc` and checked the registry but no luck: If I run `vssadmin list writers` the system writer is still not in the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone have issues with this patch on windows 2012 server (non-R2)? I get a message that informs me that this is not compatible with this operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the Problem.

If you have Visual Studio installed on the server this Hotfix from Microsoft is the Solution:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2807849/en-us

Cause:

> This issue occurs because Windows Server limits any directory from containing more than 1,000 subdirectories. Visual Studio 2012 installs more than 1,000 subdirectories in the following location:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net
>   Therefore, when the system state writer tries to back up the folder, the issue that is described in "Symptoms" section occurs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It thought this hot fix would work, but there is no download for Server 2012 at the Microsoft link.

Comment: Looks like you have to use the Windows 8 package for Server 2012 now. Thanks @Amund Thompson

Comment: I moved to VS2015, this no longer seems to be a problem.

Comment: I entered the Microsoft page through the link above and downloaded the hotfix and it worked. My "system writer" was gone after installing SQL 2017 on a Windows Server 2012 and was no longer backing up. I installed the fix, I rebooted and now the backups are back to normal. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2012 file information notes

Important Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 hotfixes are included in the same packages. However, only "Windows 8" is listed on the Hotfix Request page. To request the hotfix package that applies to one or both operating systems, select the hotfix that is listed under "Windows 8" on the page. Always refer to the "Applies To" section in articles to determine the actual operating system that each hotfix applies to.
The files that apply to a specific product, milestone (RTM,SPn), and service branch (LDR, GDR) can be identified by examining the file version numbers as shown in the following table: